# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable, How to add a dictionary with lists to html UI

Tags: html, dictionary, bottle, mako

I am new to FE web,

I am trying to show a datatable that constructs from a dictionary with lists inside. mt backend is python bottle.

This is my mako code:

```
<div class="row align-to-center">
            <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Source</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Source zone</th>
                <th>Destination zone</th>
                <th>UID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        % for key, value in rules.items:
            % for src in value["src_network"]:
                % for dst in value["dst_network"]:
                   % for service in value["dst_service"]:
            <tr>
                <td>${src["name"]}</td>
                <td>${dst["name"]}</td>
                <td>${service["name"]}</td>
                <td>${value["action"]}</td>
                <td>${value["from_zone"]}</td>
                <td>${value["to_zone"]}</td>
                <td>${key}</td>
            </tr>
        % endfor
        % endfor
        % endfor
        % endfor
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate over a function object. You must call the .items method.

Change `% for key, value in rules.items:` to `% for key, value in rules.items():`